# What is the "icon" parameter in wp_get_attachment_image_src used for?

Tags: functions, attachments

On the reference page for [`wp_get_attachment_image_src`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_get_attachment_image_src), there is a parameter called `icon` and it only says:

```
$icon - (bool) (optional) Use a media icon to represent the attachment. 
Default: false
```

What is this used for and how does it affect the returned value?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a icon with which to display the attachment. If it isn't set, it uses the default icon. The exception here is for **images**: the returned values always refer to the thumbnail (of size set in the arguments of `wp_get_attachment_image_src`). Icons are always shown at their original size.

If the attachment was an audio file, it would use the audio icon, unless otherwise specified using the `icon` argument. See the ['Change Icon Directory'](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_get_attachment_image_src#Change_Icon_Directory) section of the link you gave in the question.

Comment: Upvoted, with a minor clarification: I think that the default behavior is to display the image *thumbnail*, not an icon. The `$icon` parameter is used to display a mime-type icon in *place of* the actual image thumbnail. See the [function definition in source](http://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/3.3.1/wp-includes/media.php#L605).

Comment: Yep, but I think it **always** uses a thumbnail for images rather than an icon, right? - since `image_downsize` would return something.

Comment: Right; it appears the mime-type icon only appears for *non-images*.